# sql to group table of product owners with a column for primary owner and concatenated secondary owners

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, concatenation

I have a table of products with their owners. Each owner is in their own row and has an owner type of either primary or secondary. Not every product has a secondary owner.

I need to get a table grouped by product with the primary owner in one column and all the secondary owners concatenated in a second column. If a product has multiple primary owners it should select the first one and the rest go to the secondary owners.  If a product doesn't have a primary owner then it should just select the first/any secondary owner.

This is an input table:

```
+---------+------------+----------+
| Product | Owner Type |  Owner   |
+---------+------------+----------+
| a       | primary    | one      |
| a       | secondary  | two      |
| a       | secondary  | three    |
| b       | primary    | four     |
| b       | secondary  | five     |
| c       | primary    | six      |
| d       | secondary  | seven    |
| e       | secondary  | eight    |
| e       | secondary  | nine     |
| f       | primary    | ten      |
| f       | primary    | eleven   |
| f       | secondary  | twelve   |
| f       | secondary  | thirteen |
+---------+------------+----------+
```

The expected result is:

```
+---------+---------------+--------------------------+
| Product | Primary Owner |     Secondary Owners     |
+---------+---------------+--------------------------+
| a       | one           | two, three               |
| b       | four          | five                     |
| c       | six           |                          |
| d       | seven         |                          |
| e       | eight         | nine                     |
| f       | ten           | eleven, twelve, thirteen |
+---------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

If you notice, products `d` and `e` don't have a primary owner so it picks the first secondary owner and then doesn't include it again in the secondary owner column. Similar for product `f` that has two primary owner.

I know how to `group` by product and use `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate rows/fields. In the `group` I know how to select the first product where `Owner Type` is `primary`. What I cannot figure out is the logic that would be needed to pick the first primary owner and exclude it from the secondary owner column and/or select the first secondary owner if there is no primary owner and exclude it from the secondary owner column.

I don't even know where to start with the SQL.

Any ideas?

Comment: how should a *first* row be selected? is there a column to specify the ordering?

Comment: @vkp doesn't matter. no need to sort. just select first. if sorting is necessary then could sort by owner column.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is assigning row numbers prioritizing owner_type='Primary' rows. Then get the first row as the primary owner and `group_concat` others to be secondary owners.

```
select product
,max(case when rnum=1 then owner end) as primary_owner
,group_concat(case when rnum<>1 then owner end order by rnum) as secondary_owners
from (select product,owner_type,owner,
      @rn:=case when @prev_product=product then @rn+1 else 1 end as rnum,
      @prev_product:=product 
      from tablename 
      cross join (select @rn:=0,@prev_product:='',@prev) r
      order by product,owner_type='Primary',owner
     ) t
group by product
order by 1
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/JSRTQ97807)

Comment: This looks promising. I will give this a try. Thanks! Then I'll have to figure out how it actually works cause this introduces a lot of things I'm not familiar with.

Comment: So this did what I need for now but now we're being forced to SQL Server 2014 which does not have `group_concat`. Any ideas?