# SQL to group one column of a table, select one value from another column, and concatenate the rest

Tags: group-by, concatenation, sql-server-2014

I had asked this question before ([sql to group table of product owners with a column for primary owner and concatenated secondary owners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746314/sql-to-group-table-of-product-owners-with-a-column-for-primary-owner-and-concate)) but it was for MySQL and the answer uses `group_concat` which isn't available on SQL Server 2014. Since that one was answered and for MySQL I thought I should ask a new one for SQL Server 2014.

I have a table of products with their owners. Each owner is in their own row and has an owner type of either primary or secondary. Not every product has a secondary owner.

I need to get a table grouped by product with the primary owner in one column and all the secondary owners concatenated in a second column. If a product has multiple primary owners it should select the first one and the rest go to the secondary owners.  If a product doesn't have a primary owner then it should just select the first/any secondary owner.

This is an input table:

```
+---------+------------+----------+
| Product | Owner Type |  Owner   |
+---------+------------+----------+
| a       | primary    | one      |
| a       | secondary  | two      |
| a       | secondary  | three    |
| b       | primary    | four     |
| b       | secondary  | five     |
| c       | primary    | six      |
| d       | secondary  | seven    |
| e       | secondary  | eight    |
| e       | secondary  | nine     |
| f       | primary    | ten      |
| f       | primary    | eleven   |
| f       | secondary  | twelve   |
| f       | secondary  | thirteen |
+---------+------------+----------+
```

The expected result is:

```
+---------+---------------+--------------------------+
| Product | Primary Owner |     Secondary Owners     |
+---------+---------------+--------------------------+
| a       | one           | two, three               |
| b       | four          | five                     |
| c       | six           |                          |
| d       | seven         |                          |
| e       | eight         | nine                     |
| f       | ten           | eleven, twelve, thirteen |
+---------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

If you notice, products `d` and `e` don't have a primary owner so it picks the first secondary owner and then doesn't include it again in the secondary owner column. Similar for product `f` that has two primary owner.

I know how to `group` by product and use `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate rows/fields. In the `group` I know how to select the first product where `Owner Type` is `primary`. What I cannot figure out is the logic that would be needed to pick the first primary owner and exclude it from the secondary owner column and/or select the first secondary owner if there is no primary owner and exclude it from the secondary owner column.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the working query with the `FOR XML PATH` ugliness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your sample data, I got it to work like this using `ROW_NUMBER()` and common table expressions to decide the primary and secondary owners.

```
WITH PrimaryOwners AS
(SELECT Product,Owner AS 'Primary Owner'
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Product) 'RowNumber',
       Product,OwnerType,Owner
        FROM Product) AS tableA
WHERE RowNumber = 1),

SecondaryOwners AS
(SELECT Product,Owner AS 'Secondary Owners'
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Product) 'RowNumber',
       Product,OwnerType,Owner
        FROM Product) AS tableB
WHERE RowNumber <> 1),

SecondaryOwnersGrouped AS
(SELECT DISTINCT Product,
        STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + [Secondary Owners]
            FROM SecondaryOwners a
            WHERE a.Product = b.Product
            for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS 'Secondary Owners'
FROM SecondaryOwners b)

SELECT p.Product,p.[Primary Owner],
       ISNULL(s.[Secondary Owners],'') 'Secondary Owners'
FROM PrimaryOwners p
     LEFT JOIN SecondaryOwnersGrouped s
        ON p.Product = s.Product
```

Results:

```
+----------+----------------+------------------------ --+
| Product  | Primary Owner  | Secondary Owners          |
+----------+----------------+---------------------------+
|   a      |    one         |     two, three            |
|   b      |    four        |        five               |
|   c      |    six         |                           |
|   d      |    seven       |                           |
|   e      |    eight       |        nine               |
|   f      |    ten         | eleven, twelve, thirteen  |
+----------+----------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: You have opened my eyes. This is perfect. Thank you so much! Since the first two CTEs use the same FROM/SELECT, would it make sense to CTE that too?

Comment: The `WHERE` is different in the 1st and 2nd CTE's.  Whether or not the row number is 1 determines if it should be a primary owner, so the first 2 would need to remain seperate. You probably could combine the 2nd and 3rd CTE, but it would be as easy to read the query.

Comment: I mean make the inner SELECT (`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() ...Product`) a CTE and then just reference it? I tested it and it works but wasn't sure if there was a reason not to do that.

Comment: Also, wouldn't the `PARTITION BY` need to also order by `owner type` to ensure `primary` is always above `secondary`?

Comment: Sweet. This worked great! Before I had like 4-5 queries to do this. Thanks so much!